# Google map javascript not loading in div

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have put the google map in my html website. javascript function:

```
  <script>
      var map;
      function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
          center: {lat: 53.5796916, lng: -2.3755709},
          zoom: 17
        });
      }
    </script>

 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=mykeyhere&callback=initMap"></script>
```

and in the html:

```
<div class="map-container">
    <div id="map" class="google-map"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: @EmielZuurbier div id="map" is in my html and getelementbyid("map") in javascript? what do you mean?

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-vhhniq?file=index.html ... its working for me as expected

Comment: What does your CSS look like?  My guess is your `<div id="map">` doesn't have a size.  Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates your issue.

Comment: @GazSmith see my reply

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The messages you see have nothing to do with your code.

Place script call 
`<script type="text/javascript" src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=mykeyhere&callback=initMap"></script>`
    before `</body>` tag. 
Since when you call it `#map` is not loaded yet.

Edit:
And add something like `height: 300px;` to `#map`